# android: "adb shell" command not gives result

Tags: android, adt

I have met a strange problem, when I input the "adb shell" command, it just hang there forever, like below (the cursor is in the start of the line below "adb shell")

[image]

Just inputing the "adb" command is ok and got the instructions. Other command, like "android" also are ok.

My android version is adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.

Anybody know about this?

------UPDATE-----

When I change eclipse into DDMS view, it is not responding and so eclipse is blocked. I suspect the adb has some problem...Just dont know what problems

Comment: there is any device connected ?

Comment: When I change eclipse into DDMS view, it is not responding and so eclipse is blocked. I suspect the adb has some problem...Just dont know what problems

Comment: try restarting your OS with all android devices unplugged

Comment: what do you get by `adb devices` command?

Comment: Also blocked. Very strange. I changed back to an old version, its working...

Comment: try "adb kill-server  && adb start-server"

Comment: Did you install USB Driver? Make sure you follow this [guide](http://forums.androidcentral.com/epic-4g-rooting-roms-hacks/33427-how-access-your-adb-shell.html#post_message_332173).